# How can I catch SIGINT without closing xterm?

Tags: bash, signals

Here is my script;

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' SIGINT
xterm  &
wait
```

I run it and an xterm pops up. Then I focus my keyboard on the originating terminal window and hit `^C`. I would like nothing to happen, but instead the child xterm goes away.

(Ideally, I want to install my own trap handler, but this is a baby step)

Using `disown` after forking xterm detaches the xterm from the parent and then `^C` doesn't do anything to the xterm, but then `wait` doesn't work.

I just want to block SIGINT from getting to xterm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send SIGINT to bash script the signal is propagate to current process in the script, then it executes command in trap. So "wait" is interrupted. You must do that "wait" run again.

Also you must do that all jobs are launched in their own process groups (`set -m`).  From the set man page:

> set -m
>
> Monitor  mode.  Job control is enabled.  This option is on by default for interactive shells on systems that support it (see JOB
>   CONTROL above).  Background processes run in a 
>   separate process group and a line containing their exit status is printed upon their completion.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
trap 'R=true' SIGINT
xterm &
while : ; do
    R=false
    wait
   [[ $R == true ]] || break
done
```

You can see commands that it run with '-x' option in shebang.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `CTRL+C` will send `SIGINT` signal to each process under the same group of the foreground process's. So xterm goes away too. You can use setsid to change the group id of xterm's.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "Caught SIGINT"' SIGINT
setsid xterm &
wait
```

`wait` will be interrupted by `SIGINT` too. So if you want to `wait` after pressing `CTRL+C`, you need to wait again according to suggestion of @fbohorquez.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'R=true;echo "Caught SIGINT"' SIGINT
setsid xterm &
while : ; do
    R=false
    wait
    [ $R == false ] && break
done
```

Comment: @heemayl `wait` will also be interrupted by `SIGINT`. So if you want to `wait` after pressing `CTRL+C`, you have to `wait` again like what @fbohorquez has done.

Comment: Nice. The `setsid` trick works in Code::Blocks to launch a console application which handles the Ctrl-C itself. This prevents the terminal closing prematurely and interrupting the debugger.